# Is it possible to combine these three tensors into a large tensor as model input without using dict?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network

I have a ANN network, and not I need a dict that combines these three tensors as input, for example,

```
model = MyNetwork("mypath")
dummy_input = {}
dummy_input["input_ids"] = torch.randint(1, 512,(1,345))
dummy_input["attention_mask"] = torch.randint(1, 512,(1,345))
dummy_input["bbox"] = torch.randint(1, 512,(1,345,4))
torch_out = model(**dummy_input) #need to decompress before input
```

Thus,I was wondering if it is possible to combined above-mentioned tensor into one tenor,
for example,

```
input_ids = torch.randint(1, 512,(1,345))
attention_mask = torch.randint(1, 512,(1,345))
bbox = torch.randint(1, 512,(1,345,4))
torch_out = model(input_ids = input_ids, attention_mask = attention_mask, bbox = bbox) #is it possible to input only one tensor to replace these three?
print(torch_out)
```

btw, the forward func of my model like that, only this three tensors is necessary,

```
def forward(
    self,
    input_ids=None,
    bbox=None,
    attention_mask=None,
    token_type_ids=None,
    valid_span=None,
    position_ids=None,
    head_mask=None,
    inputs_embeds=None,
    encoder_hidden_states=None,
    encoder_attention_mask=None,
    past_key_values=None,
    use_cache=None,
    output_attentions=None,
    output_hidden_states=None,
    return_dict=None,
    images=None,
):
```

Comment: How do you expect to feed this tensor to your model which expects `input_ids` `attention_mask` and `bbox` as separate inputs?

Comment: @lvan Hi, I want to feed to forward by one tensor,like `output = model(input)` , which input is `torch.randint()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to combine these three tensors into a single, it seems you can
work this out with a concatenation since they roughly have the same shapes:

- `input_ids` is shaped `(b, f)`
- `attention_mask` is shaped `(b, f)`
- `bbox` is shaped `(b, f, 4)`

If you concatenate along a third dimensions, you will  get a tensor of shape `(b, f, 4+1+1)`:

```
>>> x = torch.cat([input_ids.unsqueeze(-1), attention_mask.unsqueeze(-1), bbox], dim=-1)
```